# Setting multiple expectations in rspec test

Tags: ruby, rspec

How do I set multiple should expectations in RSpec?  For example, below the computer's move is one sample value but out of four possible values.  I want to pass the test of being any one of those four values.  Please help a newb?

THE CODE THAT I AM TRYING TO TEST

```
def fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign)
  second_turn_check = possible_places.select { |key, value| value == user_sign }
  @corners = { a1:@a1, a3:@a3, c1:@c1, c3:@c3 }
  kitty_fork_check = second_turn_check.keys & @corners.keys
  if kitty_fork_check == [:a1, :c3] || kitty_fork_check == [:a3, :c1]
    move = { a2:@a2, b3:@b3, c2:@c2, b1:@b1 }.keys.sample
    #declare_computer_move(move)
  else
    #fork_detection_type_2
  end
end
```

THE TEST EFFECT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE

```
 it "should be returning only a sample edge move value when there is a kitty fork type" do
   possible_places = {a1: "X",a2: @a2,a3: @a3,b1: @b1,b2: @b2,b3: @b3,c1: @c1,c2: @c2,c3: "X"}
   user_sign = "X"

   test_case = ComputerLogic.new
   test_case.fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign).should == :a2 || 
   test_case.fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign).should == :b3 || 
   test_case.fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign).should == :c2 || 
   test_case.fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign).should == :b1
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by computing a boolean expression and comparing the result to `true` or you can define your own matcher.

An example of the former approach, using the `expect` syntax, would be:

```
expect([:a2,:b3,:c2,:b1].include?(
  test_case.fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign)).to be true
```

An example of the latter approach would be:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :be_one_of do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.include?(actual)
  end
end
```

with the following expectation:

```
expect(test_case.fork_detection_type_1(possible_places, user_sign)).to
  be_one_of([:a2,:b3,:c2,:b1])
```

per https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/define-matcher!#define-a-matcher-with-default-messages

Comment: the latter approach worked.  the first one gave the error of undefined method include?...